# Why does this controller double the inserts when I try to archive the results of the Bing Search API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bing-api, asynccontroller

I'm trying to archive my search results for a term by

1. Using the Bing API in an async controller
2. Inserting them into database using Entity Framework

using the Bing API and insert them into a database using entity framework.  For whatever reason it is returning 50 results, but then it enters 100 results into the database.

My Controller Code:

```
public class DHWebServicesController : AsyncController
    {
        //
        // GET: /WebService/

        private DHContext context = new DHContext();


        [HttpPost]
        public void RunReportSetAsync(int id)
        {
            int iTotalCount = 1;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment(iTotalCount);
            if (!context.DHSearchResults.Any(xx => xx.CityMarketComboRunID == id))
            {

                string strBingSearchUri = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BingSearchURI"];
                string strBingAccountKey = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BingAccountKey"];
                string strBingUserAccountKey = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BingUserAccountKey"];
                CityMarketComboRun cityMarketComboRun = context.CityMarketComboRuns.Include(xx => xx.CityMarketCombo).Include(xx => xx.CityMarketCombo.City).First(xx => xx.CityMarketComboRunID == id);

                var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri(strBingSearchUri));
                bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strBingUserAccountKey, strBingAccountKey);
                // now we can build the query

                Keyword keyword = context.Keywords.First();
                var bingWebQuery = bingContainer.Web(keyword.Name, "en-US", "Moderate", cityMarketComboRun.CityMarketCombo.City.Latitude, cityMarketComboRun.CityMarketCombo.City.Longitude, null, null, null);
                var bingWebResults = bingWebQuery.Execute();

                context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                int i = 1;
                DHSearchResult dhSearchResult = new DHSearchResult();
                List<DHSearchResult> lst = new  List<DHSearchResult>();
                var webResults = bingWebResults.ToList();
                foreach (var  result in webResults)
                {
                    dhSearchResult = new DHSearchResult();
                    dhSearchResult.BingID = result.ID;
                    dhSearchResult.CityMarketComboRunID = id;
                    dhSearchResult.Description = result.Description;
                    dhSearchResult.DisplayUrl = result.DisplayUrl;
                    dhSearchResult.KeywordID = keyword.KeywordID;
                    dhSearchResult.Created = DateTime.Now;
                    dhSearchResult.Modified = DateTime.Now;
                    dhSearchResult.Title = result.Title;
                    dhSearchResult.Url = result.Url;
                    dhSearchResult.Ordinal = i;
                    lst.Add(dhSearchResult);
                    i++;
                }

                foreach (DHSearchResult c in lst)
                {
                    context.DHSearchResults.Add(c);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                }
                AsyncManager.Parameters["message"] = "The total number of results was "+lst.Count+".  And there are " + context.DHSearchResults.Count().ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                AsyncManager.Parameters["message"] = "You have already run this report";
            }
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement(iTotalCount);
        }
        public string RunReportSetCompleted(string message)
        {
            string str = message;
            return str;
        }

    }
```

Here is how I am calling it from my asp.net mvc 4 page.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Run Report", "GatherKeywordsFromBing", "DHWebServices", 
                new { id=item.CityMarketComboRunID}, 
                new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "ShowNotifier();", UpdateTargetId = "TopNotifierMessage", HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, LoadingElementId = strCityMarketComboProgressID, LoadingElementDuration = 1000 }, 
                new { @class = "ViewLink" }) 
            <span class="ProgressIndicator" id="@strCityMarketComboProgressID"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/SmallBall.gif")" alt="loading" /></span>
```

For whatever reason all of

Comment: Why are you using an Async controller when there's nothing asynchronous in your code? It's perfectly sequential. There's no point of async controller in this case. It will only make things worse.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving only once:

```
foreach (DHSearchResult c in lst)
{
    context.DHSearchResults.Add(c);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Also there's nothing asynchronous in your code, so there's no point of using asynchronous controller. Not only that it won't improve anything but it might make things worse.

Comment: I plan on adding some async features later (i.e. it will take some time to run) and I will eventually adding a status indicator.  And I tried the method you suggested above and got the same result.  It's a perpelexing thing.